# read_csv giving error for movielens 20M dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using pandas for the first time and wanted to do some data analysis for Movielens dataset. After running my code for 1M dataset, I wanted to experiment with [Movielens 20M](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/20m/)

I am only reading one file i.e **ratings.csv**

However, I faced multiple problems with 20M dataset, and after spending much time I realized that this is because the dtypes of columns being read are not as expected.
The following code(where path is path of ratings.csv file)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('../data/ml-20m/ratings.csv',sep=',',names= 
['userId','movieId','rating','timestamp'],engine='python', dtype= 
{'userId':np.int32, 'movieId':np.int32, 'rating':np.float64, 
'timestamp':np.int64}, skipinitialspace=True, error_bad_lines=False)
```

is giving me the following error :-

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/sahildeep/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 1663, in _cast_types
>       values = astype_nansafe(values, cast_type, copy=True)   File "/home/sahildeep/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py",
>   line 709, in astype_nansafe
>       return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)   File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 456, in
>   pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe   File "pandas/_libs/src/util.pxd",
>   line 142, in util.set_value_at_unsafe ValueError: invalid literal for
>   int() with base 10: 'movieId'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 4, in
>   
>       df = pd.read_csv('../data/ml-20m/ratings.csv',sep=',',names= ['userId','movieId','rating','timestamp'],engine='python', dtype=
>   {'userId':np.int32, 'movieId':np.int32, 'rating':np.float64,
>   'timestamp':np.int64}, skipinitialspace=True, error_bad_lines=False)
>   File
>   "/home/sahildeep/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 678, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "/home/sahildeep/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 446, in _read
>       data = parser.read(nrows)   File "/home/sahildeep/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 1036, in read
>       ret = self._engine.read(nrows)   File "/home/sahildeep/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 2272, in read
>       data = self._convert_data(data)   File "/home/sahildeep/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 2338, in _convert_data
>       clean_conv, clean_dtypes)   File "/home/sahildeep/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 1574, in _convert_to_ndarrays
>       cvals = self._cast_types(cvals, cast_type, c)   File "/home/sahildeep/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py",
>   line 1666, in _cast_types
>       "type %s" % (column, cast_type)) ValueError: Unable to convert column movieId to type

Basically I want to skip all those lines whose datatype doesn't conform to dictionary
    {'userId':np.int32, 'movieId':np.int32, 'rating':np.float64, 
    'timestamp':np.int64}

If I don't give the dtype argument to read_csv, then all four columns turn out to be of type "object" which is not what I want.

I searched on google and found noone facing this problem. Can you help me?

I am using python3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you define columns names, but csv have header, so first row of `DataFrame` is same like columns names, so all rows are converted to strings:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv', 
                 names= ['userId','movieId','rating','timestamp'])
print (df.head())
    userId   movieId  rating  timestamp
0  user_id  movie_id  rating  timestamp
1        1      1193       5  978300760
2        1       661       3  978302109
3        1       914       3  978301968
4        1      3408       4  978300275
```

Solution is use parameter `skiprows=1` or `header=0` for rename columns names by `names` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv', 
                 dtype= {'userId':np.int32, 
                         'movieId':np.int32, 
                         'rating':np.float64, 
                         'timestamp':np.int64},
                 header=0, #skiprows=1
                 names= ['userId','movieId','rating','timestamp'])
print (df.head())

   userId  movieId  rating  timestamp
0       1     1193     5.0  978300760
1       1      661     3.0  978302109
2       1      914     3.0  978301968
3       1     3408     4.0  978300275
4       1     2355     5.0  978824291
```

If dont want rename column names:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv', 
                 dtype= {'userId':np.int32, 
                         'movieId':np.int32, 
                         'rating':np.float64, 
                         'timestamp':np.int64})

print (df.head())

   user_id  movie_id  rating  timestamp
0        1      1193     5.0  978300760
1        1       661     3.0  978302109
2        1       914     3.0  978301968
3        1      3408     4.0  978300275
4        1      2355     5.0  978824291
```

Comment: Thanks, can I instead add skiprows=1 in read_csv call? Will that do the same?

Comment: @KartikMahajan - if want `rename` column by `names`, then yes, check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my newbie question